# Inventory planning problem solved through dynamic programming

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, check-my-algorithm

I am working on problem (15-11) Inventory planning from *Introduction to Algorithms* (CLRS, 3rd Ed).

> **15-11: Inventory Planning, p.411**
>
> The Rinky Dink Company makes machines that resurface ice rinks. The demand for such products varies from month to month, and so the company needs to develop a strategy to plan its manufacturing given the fluctuating, but predictable, demand. The company wishes to design a plan for the next $n$ months. For each month $i$, the company knows the demand $d_i$, that is, the number of machines that it will sell. Let $D  = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i $ be the total demand over the next $n$ months. The company keeps a full-time staff who provide labor to manufacture up to m machines in a given month, it can hire additional, part-time labor, at a cost that works out to c dollars per machine. Furthermore, if, at the end of a month, the company is holding any unsold machines, it must pay inventory costs. The cost for holding j machines is given as a function $h(j)$ for $u = 1, 2, ... , D$, where $h(j) \ge 0$ for $1 \le j \le D$ and $h(j) \le h(j+1)$ for $j \le 1 \le D - 1$.
> Give an algorithm that calculates a plan for the company that minimizes its costs while fulfilling all the demand. The running time should be polynomical in $n$ and $D$.

In other words, problem asks to create dynamic programming algorithm that solves this problem.

So far, I came up the the following solution, and not sure if it is any good.
Optimal sub-problem:
Let $MinCost(i,j)$ be the function that returns minimized cost of operation for past $i$ months, $j$ is the number of unsold machines left at the end of the month $i$.(Goal, is to calculate $MinCost(n,0)$, in other words, at the end of planning period(month $n$), there are no unsold machines.)

So, the DP recurrence is given by $MinCost(0,0) = 0$ and

$\quad MinCost(i,j) = \min\{MinCost(i-1,j-k) + c(k,j,i) + h(j) \mid 1 \le k \le D \}$

for $i+j > 0$; here, $c(k,j,i)$ is the function that calculates the costs of the production.

If my optimal sub-problem is correct, how do I create an algorithm to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

CLRS give plenty of implementations in their chapter on dynamic programming, e.g. in the section on Rod cutting

- recursive top-down (p363),
- memoized (p365f) and
- bottom-up (p366).

I suggest you try to adapt one of these.

Answer (score 0):

The overal idea of the sub-problem sounds good.

I've noticed a few issues:

###### What is k supposed to represent?

$j$ represents the number of machines unsold at the end of month $i$. This can't be negative as you cannot have a negative number of machines unsold, which means you sold more than what you produced!

You said you start with $MinCost(n,0)$ so you start with $j=0$, but then you need to compute $MinCost(n-1,0-k)$ and you wrote that $1 \leq k$, which leaves to negative $j$!. There seem to be an issue here.

I think your idea was that $k$ was the net difference of machines unsold on day $i$, which makes it hard to reason about.

**So let's define $k$ as the number of unsold machines at the beginning of month $i$** (= number of unsold at the end of month $i-1$).

###### What is $c(k,j,i)$?

You should have enough data to compute the costs yourself. By the new definition of $k$, $c(k,j,i)= c \cdot (j-k + d_i - m)$. This is because you had $k$ machine at the beginning of month $i$, you have $j$ machines at the end of that month and you sold $d_i$ machines, so you produced $j-k + d_i$ machines that month. You can produce $m$ machines without any additional cost so the remaining number of machine costs $c$ dollars per machine.

Please note that this value cannot be negative, as you can't get back the costs if you have to build less than $m$ machines. So $c(k,j,i)= max(0, c \cdot (j-k + d_i - m))$.

###### This brings us to

$\quad MC(i,j) = \min\{MC(i-1,k) + max(0, c \cdot (j-k + d_i - m)) + h(j) \mid 0 \le k \le D \}$

With $MC(0, j) =
  \begin{cases}
    0      & \quad \text{if } i = 0\\
    + \infty  & \quad \text{if } i \neq 0
  \end{cases}$

Because you can't have machines in stock before the first day.

We could make some optimisation on the max value of $k$ but it's a bit hard to compute and won't improve the asymptotic complexity.

I believe this should be enough to write the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I was visiting the dynamic programming questions in the CLRS the other day, and I saw this problem. I think this can be solved in $O(nD)$.

Let $C(i,j)$ be the minimum cost of producing a total of $1 \leq j \leq D$ machines at the end of $1 \leq i \leq n$ months. Since the production must meet the demand, if we have $j < \sum_{k=1}^i d_k$ at month $i$ (i.e., we couldn't meet the demand), we set $C(i,j) = \infty$ since this is not a valid solution. Otherwise, at month $i$ to produce $j$ machines, where $j \geq \sum_{k=1}^i d_k$, we have the choice of producing $l \leq j$ machines in $i-1$ months and $j-l$ machines this month. The optimal cost of the former is given by $C(i-1,l)$ and the cost of the latter is $c \cdot (j-l-m)$. Since this value cannot be negative, we can rewrite it as $c \cdot max(0, (j-l-m))$, which makes the cost $0$ if it is negative. We also need to store the extra produced machines that are over the demand in an inventory, whose cost is $h(j-\sum_{k=1}^i d_k)$. This must be added to the cost above. Let $C$ be an $(n+1) \times D$ matrix. We also compute the cumulative summation of demands in an array $A$ to help checking whether we meet the demand in a particular month. Then the recursive formulation becomes:

\begin{equation}
  C(i,j) =
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if } i=0 \\
      \infty, & \text{if } j < A[i] \\
      min_{1\leq k \leq j} (C(i-1,k) + (c \cdot max((j-k-m),0)) + h(j-A[i])), & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

The above formulation looks like $O(nD^2)$. But assume we computed $C(i,j)$ and this cell chose some $k$ in row $i-1$ as minimum. While computing $C(i,j+1)$ the minimum cell in the above row for it must either be again $k$ (i.e., $C(i-1,k)$) or $C(i-1,j+1)$. The former is because $h(j) \leq h(j+1)$ and we would choose the same minimum in the above row when computing for $j+1$ if we did not consider $C(i-1,j+1)$. By keeping a running minimum for row $i-1$, thus the runtime can be reduced to $O(nD)$.